# FCM web messages received on Android but not iOS

Tags: php, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to send push notifications from a php script via FCM to Android and iOS.
When I send a test message from the FCM console everything works fine on both Android and iOS (I use the registration token as target in the console).
But when I send it from my php script, only Android receives the messages, not iOS.
I use the following script:

```
<?php

function sendNotificationFCM($title, $id)
{
    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $apikey = "[Server Key on FCM]";
    
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization:key=".$apikey,
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    );

    $notifData = [
        'title' => "Title",
        'body' => $title
    ];

    $dataPayload = [
        'sound' => 'default',
        'id' => $id
    ];

    $notifBody = [
        "notification" => $notifData,
        "data" => $dataPayload,
        "priority" => "high",
        "to" => "/topics/general"
      ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($notifBody));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "result: ".$result;

    curl_close($ch);
}

sendNotificationFCM("Test", "24");
```

Any idea?

Comment: Solved. I simply forgot to register for the topic "general" in my iOS code (using Xamarin).